# iterate over certain columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have data frame like this:

```
    Ticker  P/E     P/S     P/B    P/FCF    Dividend
No.                     
1   NTCT    457.32  3.03    1.44    26.04   -
2   GWRE    416.06  9.80    5.33    45.62   -
3   PEGA    129.02  4.41    9.85    285.10  0.28%
4   BLKB    87.68   4.96    14.36   41.81   0.62%
```

Firstly, I want to convert values in columns that contain numbers (which are string currently) to a float values. So here I would have the 4 middle columns that need the conversion to float. Would simple loop work with this case?

Second thing, there is a problem with the last column `'Dividend'` where there is a percentage value as string. As a matter of fact I can convert it to decimals, however I was thinking if there is a way to still retaining the % and the values would still be calculable.

Any ideas for those two issues?

Comment: You mean the one I deleted? Yeah I fixed it and asked again but got downwote anyway so well it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***plan***

- Take out `'Ticker'` because it isn't numeric
- use `assign` to overwrite `Dividend` by striping off `%`
- use `apply` with `pd.to_numeric` to convert all the columns
- use `eval` to get `Dividend` to proper decimal space

---

---

```
df[['Ticker']].join(
    df.assign(
        Dividend=df.Dividend.str.strip('%')
    ).drop('Ticker', 1).apply(
        pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'
    )
).eval('Dividend = Dividend / 100', inplace=False)

    Ticker     P/E   P/S    P/B   P/FCF  Dividend
No.                                              
1     NTCT  457.32  3.03   1.44   26.04       NaN
2     GWRE  416.06  9.80   5.33   45.62       NaN
3     PEGA  129.02  4.41   9.85  285.10    0.0028
4     BLKB   87.68  4.96  14.36   41.81    0.0062
```

---

***more lines***
*more readable*

```
nums = df.drop('Ticker', 1).assign(Dividend=df.Dividend.str.strip('%'))
nums = nums.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
nums = nums.assign(Dividend=nums.Dividend / 100)
df[['Ticker']].join(nums)

    Ticker     P/E   P/S    P/B   P/FCF  Dividend
No.                                              
1     NTCT  457.32  3.03   1.44   26.04       NaN
2     GWRE  416.06  9.80   5.33   45.62       NaN
3     PEGA  129.02  4.41   9.85  285.10    0.0028
4     BLKB   87.68  4.96  14.36   41.81    0.0062
```

Comment: So converting percents into decimal numbers is the only way to go right?

Comment: @AlexT no!  I just haven't figured it out yet. The way to go is to create a custom class called percent that inherits from float but you override the __repr__ method. Problem is that when I did that pandas or numpy converts it back to floats. I'm curious about how to stop this. I'd like to use it as well. Just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Do you think setting float display format to this one would solve the issue? `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format`
Howevr it should apply to one column only :/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all `P/...` columns contain proper numbers:

```
In [47]: df.assign(Dividend=pd.to_numeric(df.Dividend.str.replace(r'\%',''), errors='coerce')
    ...:                      .div(100)) \
    ...:   .set_index('Ticker', append=True) \
    ...:   .astype('float') \
    ...:   .reset_index('Ticker')
    ...:
Out[47]:
    Ticker     P/E   P/S    P/B   P/FCF  Dividend
No.
1     NTCT  457.32  3.03   1.44   26.04       NaN
2     GWRE  416.06  9.80   5.33   45.62       NaN
3     PEGA  129.02  4.41   9.85  285.10    0.0028
4     BLKB   87.68  4.96  14.36   41.81    0.0062
```